# Using ANT to build swc, cannot find catalog.xml

Tags: apache-flex, ant

I'm trying to build an SWC (in Flex 4.6) using ANT. This is what my build.xml looks like right now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="imanager-framework" basedir=".">

    <property name="src" location="src"/>   
    <property name="dist" location="dist"/> 
    <property name="FLEX_HOME" value="C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/sdks/4.6.0"/>        

    <taskdef resource="flexTasks.tasks" classpath="${basedir}/libs/flexTasksFlash4.jar"/>

    <target name="clean">       
        <delete dir="${dist}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${dist}"/>
        <compc output="${dist}/imanager-framework.swc">
            <source-path path-element="src" />
            <library-path dir="libs" includes="*" />
            <include-sources dir="${src}" includes="*" />           
        </compc>
    </target>

</project>
```

And flexTasks.tasks looks like this

```
mxmlc=flex.ant.MxmlcTask
compc=flex.ant.CompcTask
html-wrapper=flex.ant.HtmlWrapperTask
asdoc=flex.ant.AsDocTask
```

When I run the build, I get the this error

```
Buildfile: E:\flexspace\imanager\framework\build.xml
compile:
    [compc] Loading configuration file C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\flex-config.xml
    [compc] Error: unable to load SWC flexTasksFlash4.jar: could not find catalog.xml within the SWC.

BUILD FAILED
E:\flexspace\imanager\framework\build.xml:16: compc task failed

Total time: 639 milliseconds
```

It appears that compc is trying to read the flexTasks jar as an SWC. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, that you `jar` library with tasks definitions is in the `libs` dir as all the `swc` files, compiler tries to use it as an `swc` library. And since `jar` and `swc` are both archives, compiler extracts them and tries to find `catalog.xml` inside, but jar is not flash library and does not contain it. I suggest you to put jar to some another location and leave only `swc` files inside lib. Or specify swc pattern

```
<library-path dir="libs" includes="*.swc" />
```